# Spring-Data: Define <mongo:jmx> using java based config

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-java-config

When using spring data mongo, how can you do `<mongo:jmx />` in java based config?

Comment: I am looking for this too :)

Answer (score 2):

Spring does not (yet?) support this. You have two options:

1. Include all beans in Java Config

Beans are found in MongoJmxParser.registerJmxComponents().

```
  @Bean
public MBeanExporter sportsbookMBeanExporter() throws MalformedObjectNameException {
    MBeanExporter exporter = new MBeanExporter();
    exporter.setAssembler(new SimpleReflectiveMBeanInfoAssembler());
    exporter.setNamingStrategy(new MBeanObjectNamingStrategy());
    Map<String, Object> beanMap = new HashMap<>();
    beanMap.put("AssertMetrics", AssertMetrics.class);
    beanMap.put("BackgroundFlushingMetrics", BackgroundFlushingMetrics.class);
    beanMap.put("BtreeIndexCounters", BtreeIndexCounters.class);
    beanMap.put("ConnectionMetrics", ConnectionMetrics.class);
    beanMap.put("GlobalLockMetrics", GlobalLockMetrics.class);
    beanMap.put("MemoryMetrics", MemoryMetrics.class);
    beanMap.put("OperationCounters", OperationCounters.class);
    beanMap.put("ServerInfo", ServerInfo.class);
    beanMap.put("MongoAdmin", MongoAdmin.class);
    exporter.setBeans(beanMap);
    return exporter;
}
```

2. Create a minimal xml-config

Recommended since beans might change for new releases.

In JavaConfig:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:spring.xml")
```

under src/main/resources add a file spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <!--not possible to enable in Java Config-->
    <mongo:jmx/>
</beans>
```